# Is a <head> element always available in the DOM, even if absent in the HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document, domdocument

Every browser I've observed creates a `<head>` element that's accessible in the DOM even if there are no explicit `<head></head>` tags in the document's markup.

However, Google Analytics uses the following code for dynamic script insertion:

```
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script');
  ga.type = 'text/javascript';
  ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
})();
```

The following line:

```
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
```

seems to make a special concession for cases where a `<head>` element is not present.

Is this just a case of extreme backwards-compatibility (e.g., for Netscape 4, or the like), or is there a case to be made for not assuming that modern browsers (i.e., Internet Explorer 6 and more recent) will always have access to a `<head>` element in the DOM?

Comment: IE6 and even IE5.5 add a `HEAD` element if not present, other browsers like Safari <= 4 don't, also maybe some old Opera versions IIRC.

Comment: Thanks, CMS! IE 6 is about as far back as I've supported in a long time, so it makes sense that I've just become used to the browser adding a `<head>` automagically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The modern browsers are creating the head element for you when needed.

But assuming that the client will do so is not smart if you want your code to be bullet-proof. So the Googlers are being conservative and safe.

The extra clause in their statement is de minimus, but adds additional reliability. So it's a good thing.

ps Good job on the question and pulling out the relevant code.

**Added:**

The [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#edef-HEAD) says that the head tag is optional. I don't think the browers' creation of the head "element" in the dom is required by the spec. Google doesn't want to (and shouldn't) count on it being there.

Comment: The HTML 4.01 spec says that the head *element* is required. Only the *tags* are optional. See http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#edef-HTML . Browsers, of course, frequently do not follow the specs and if they consistently automagically create the head element, it'll be because significant numbers of real world web pages break in browsers that don't do so.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks very much for your help.

@Alohci: Thanks for the extra input - that makes sense.

Comment: I'm confused...head **element** is required, but **tags** are optional...How could you define a head **element** without the <head></head> **tags**?

Comment: @user1036719 -- you could programmatically create the element within the dom even though the html tag was not present in the html itself.

Comment: Larry: Hmm. What does "required" mean then? Required *when*? Also note that the same logic should have applied to e.g. the `TITLE` (being a child of `HEAD`) then, but the same std. said there: *"Start tag: required, End tag: required"*. Something else must have been the answer to  @user1036719's question. Perhaps user agents were simply required to *imply* the `HEAD` element where is should be, regardless of its tags. Which they all do, BTW.

Comment: OK, it's [explicitly explained in the current std](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/document-metadata.html#the-head-element):
*"A head element’s start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the head element is an element.
A head element’s end tag may be omitted if the head element is not immediately followed by a space character or a comment."*

Answer (score 2):

In fact, not all the browser automatically create `<head></head>` when the document is load. I mean not even on modern browser such as Chrome (Version: 9.0.597.102).

When you load an image directly to the browser, like for example:
`http://www.stylesight.com/assets/external/home_carousel/en/materials_ss12_m.jpg`,
the browser will only generate the `<body>` tag to contain the image and the `<head>` tag can not be found on the source code.

Google using this code:

```
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
```

We can not create `<head>` using `document.createElement('head')`: using that will get an error: `"Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3"`.
Thus when there's no head tag, you cannot append anything to it. That's why google put the element into the `<body>` instead.

Comment: +1 Could you please add a reference to the statement that one can not dynamically create a `head` tag?

Comment: @GitaarLAB: The `"Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3"` is a reference assuming it's copied from a browser console. It would be nice to indicate *which* browser generates that though.

Comment: @slebetman: indeed, I meant: which browsers throw this and some (authoritative) online source that 'documents' this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not given the "head" element will always be present, it normally depends on browsers and document DOCTYPE. For a discussion and several tests on this see:

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/05/12/autohead-my-first-browserscope-user-test/

The following will take care of many quirks and it is the shortest reusable code for loading generic scripts (including GA and the likes):

```
function require(src) {
  var s, d = document, r = d.documentElement;
  (s = d.createElement('script')).src = src;
  r.removeChild(r.insertBefore(s, r.firstChild));
}

require(('https:' == document.location.protocol ?
  'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +
  '.google-analytics.com/ga.js');
```

here the script is also removed from the document (after being loaded/executed) but that is just personal taste, one can skip the "removeChild" if needed. There are no difference in behaviour by removing it or leave it in place.